# Export Excel with 1Million records in laravel using Maatwebsite - 500 Error Request Time-out - Internal Server Error

Tags: excel, laravel, export-to-excel, http-status-code-500, maatwebsite-excel

Here is function which I am calling for on export button

**Function**

```
public function xyzexport()
    {

        return Excel::download(new XyzExport, '13xyz-export.xlsx');
    }
```

Then **class XyzExport**

```
class XyzExport implements WithHeadings, FromCollection
{

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'xyz1',
            'xyz2',
            
        ];
    }

    public function collection()
    {
        $type = XYZ::get();
        foreach ($type as $key => $value) {
            if($type[$key]['xyz1'] != '')
            {
                $type[$key]['xyz1'] = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($type[$key]['xyz1']));
            }
            else
            {
                $type[$key]['xyz1'] = NULL;
            }
            if($type[$key]['xyz2'] != '')
            {
                $type[$key]['xyz2'] = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($type[$key]['xyz2']));
            }
            else
            {
                $type[$key]['xyz2'] = NULL;
            }
            $type[$key]['xyz1'] = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($type[$key]['xyz1']));
            $type[$key]['xyz2'] = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($type[$key]['xyz2']));
            unset($type[$key]['ID'],$type[$key]['created_at'],$type[$key]['updated_at']);
        }
        return $type;
    }
}
```

Here every time it shows me for **500 Request timeout error - Internal Server Error**

Even if I had update:

=> **memory_limit = -1**

=> **worker_connections = -1**

=> **max_execution_time = -1**

=> **post_max_size = -1**

=> **upload_max_filesize = -1**

=> **max_connections = 200**

=> **v_max_user_connections = 50**

**After doing all this permutation and combination I am not able to get the derived data of 1 Million records in excel.**

Comment: I suggest you to do your export and other manipulation using cronjob.

Comment: In my case cron will not work as i  want to download either in minute or in a year, thats not defined, so its compulsory to use this function when someone clicks on buuton.

Comment: Yeah, You have to make logic when user request for that export. your system will store the requirement and your backedn cron job will do that job. That way the end-user don't have to wait for completion of export and your server will don't get crashed because of large amount of ongoing process.

Comment: I have now tested with even cronjob and it gets expired @ApurvBhavsar

Comment: Server get expired or what?

Comment: Yes, every time it task some time and shows server expired.